# Create a Cluster Shared Volume with 3 Servers

Tags: windows, shared-folders, windows-server-2012-r2, smb, cluster

I'm new to Failover Cluster and everthing that has to do with it. At the Moment I have two Hyper-V Hosts Connected to a VLAN and a third Server which I would like to use as a Fileshare so the VMs will be High Available.

The two Hyper-V Hosts are directly connected to the third Server over Ethernet. I would like to know if it is even possible to achieve High Availablity with this Setup? I read about SMB3 but I'm not sure if this can even work because I don't know that much about it.

I don't need a step-by-step Thing on what I have to do. I just wanna know if it's possible or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In order to achieve the "True HA" which means not only the VM failover but also the storage failover, one storage host is just not enough. Single storage host is always a single point of failure. That's why HA clustering requires a shared storage.

If you have 3x Windows Server 2016 Datacenter licenses, you can consider configuring the Storage Spaces Direct. This is, essentially, a built-in hyper-converged solution from Microsoft itself: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-docs/storage/storage-spaces/storage-spaces-direct-overview

I can also recommend you to try "StarWind Virtual SAN", which is a third-party Windows-native solution that does, basically, the same thing as one above along with providing some extra features. This one can be built from 2 or 3 hosts and does not require Datacenter licenses. They also have a free version available. Take a look here: https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-san

There is also a number of other solutions available on market that can help you to get the desired result. To sum up, the answer is "Yes" you can achieve what you want :)